# Regex to match a digit not followed by a dot(".")

Tags: java, regex, eclipse

I have a string

> *string 1*(excluding the quotes) -> "my car number is #**8746253** which is actually cool"

conditions - The number 8746253, could be of any length and
           - the number can also be immediately followed by an end-of-line.

I want to group-out **8746253** which should not be followed by a dot "."
I have tried,

> .*#(\d+)[^.].*

This will get me the number for sure, but this will match even if there is a dot, because [.^] will match the last digit of the number(for example, **3** in the below case)

> *string 2*(excluding the quotes) -> "earth is #**8746253.Kms** away, which is very far"

I want to match only the ***string 1*** type and not the ***string 2*** types.

Comment: Do you need to match the whole line or just the digits? You have `.*` in the pattern, so it is a bit unclear.

Comment: it is the whole line itself. And then, i want to group out only the digit.

Comment: Ok, I added all possible solutions that came up to my mind when reading your question.

Comment: Obvious and compatible fix: [`#(\d+)(?:[^.\d]|$)`](https://regex101.com/r/6NLeNv/1)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To match any number of digits after `#` that are not followed with a dot, use

```
(?<=#)\d++(?!\.)
```

The `++` is a possessive quantifier  that will make the regex engine only check the lookahead `(?!\.)` only after the last matched digit, and won't backtrack if there is a dot after that. So, the whole match will get failed if there is a dit after the last digit in a digit chunk.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/psN8pA/1)

To match the whole line and put the digits into capture group #1:

```
.*#(\d++)(?!\.).*
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/psN8pA/2). Or a version without a lookahead:

```
^.*#(\d++)(?:[^.\r\n].*)?$
```

See [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/psN8pA/4). In this last version, the digit chunk can only be followed with an *optional sequence* of a char that is not a `.`, CR and LF followed with any 0+ chars other than line break chars (`(?:[^.\r\n].*)?`) and then the end of string (`$`).

Comment: Like always your solution work perfect, i have a question @Wiktor Stribiżew what does `\d++` why double + i think one is enough no?

Comment: @YCF_L: The `++` is a **possessive** quantifier that stops the regex engine to retry matching `\d+` pattern once there is a dot after a digit. When matching `123.` with `\d+(?!\.)`, the `3` will get failed, but the regex engine knows it can still retry `\d+` pattern to find a sequence of digits that do not end with `.`, and it finds `12` (as `3` is not a `.`). When `++` is used, the regex engine is forbidden to *backtrack* this way.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: I was wondering how I'd implement this e.g. in JavaScript which does not support lookbehinds nor this quantifier?

Comment: @eol You would use a `\d` in the negated character class as @bobblebubble just shown. In my version, `^.*#(\d+)(?:[^\d.\r\n].*)?$`. Or to just grab the digits: [`/#(\d+)(?=[^\d.]|$)/g`](https://regex101.com/r/O0ZcvB/1) into Group 1.

Comment: @atiqkhaled Do you mean `(?<=#)`? It is a positive lookahead that checks for a `#` symbol immediately to the left of the current location, and fails the match if it is missing.

Comment: ++ 'The Thing' :) game changer for me. Thank you @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I need to ask you, could you please, provide the documentation where the regular expressions would be fully documented? I checked for wikipedia article, but neither ++, nor negative lookahed were mentioned there. I struggle to understand expressions and need to have full documentation to learn regular expressions. Thank you

Comment: @TornikeShavishvili There are two great sites: http://regular-expressions.info and http://rexegg.com. There is no full documentation on all regex flavors in one place, you will need to ransack the official documentation for each regex library you are interested in.

Answer (score 1):

This works like you have described

```
public class MyRegex{   
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pattern patern = Pattern.compile("#(\\d++)[^\\.]");
        Matcher matcher1 = patern.matcher("my car number is #8746253 which is actually cool");
        if(matcher1.find()){
            System.out.println(matcher1.group(1));
        }
        Matcher matcher2 = patern.matcher("earth is #8746253.Kms away, which is very far");
        if(matcher2.find()){
            System.out.println(matcher1.group(1));
        }else{
            System.out.println("No match found");
        }
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
> 8746253 
> No match found
```